# Visualforce page within a Page Layout

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component

I have a functionality which uses Apex and VisualForce to create a multi-select picklist of record Names which is an ad-hoc list created by a query. The user can select multiple Names - and an Apex trigger will create a child record to the current record for each of the selections.

I use a VisualForce page to display the whole record. Here is an example of the VF page :

```
<apex:page standardcontroller="Breach__c" extensions="BreachVFControllerEdit">
    <apex:messages />
    <apex:sectionheader title="{!$ObjectType.Breach__c.label} Edit" subtitle="{!IF(ISNULL(Breach__c.Name), 'New Breach',Breach__c.Name)}"/>
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageblock mode="edit" title="{!$ObjectType.Breach__c.label} Edit">
            <apex:pageblockbuttons >
                <apex:commandbutton value="Save" action="{!Save}"/>
                <apex:commandbutton value="Cancel" action="{!Cancel}"/>
            </apex:pageblockbuttons>

            <!-- **********   [Record Type : Master ]   **********  -->
            <apex:outputpanel >
                <apex:pageblocksection title="Information" showheader="true" columns="1">
                    <apex:outputfield value="{!Breach__c.Name}"/>
                    <apex:inputfield value="{!Breach__c.Description__c}" required="false"/>
                    <apex:inputfield value="{!Breach__c.Date_of_Breach__c}" required="false"/>

                </apex:pageblocksection>
            </apex:outputpanel>

               <!--BEGINNING OF MULTISELECT PIECE-->
                 <apex:outputpanel id="SubsidiariesDetails2">
                  <apex:pageblocksection title="Products Affected By Breach" columns="1">
                       <apex:inputfield value="{!Breach__c.Vendor_Profile__c}" required="false" >
                       <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!execute}"             
rerender="SubsidiariesDetails2,Subsidiaries" immediate="false" /> 
                      </apex:inputfield>
                 <apex:pageBlockSectionItem id="selPanel"> 

                <c:MultiselectPicklist leftLabel="Available Products"
                    leftboxatt="{!items}"
                    rightLabel="Selected Products"
                    rightboxatt="{!selectedSubs2}"
                    size="5"
                    width="200px"/>
               <apex:inputfield value="{!Breach__c.Product_Included__c}" rendered="false" required="false"/>                   
             </apex:pageBlockSectionItem> 
          </apex:pageBlockSection>  
          </apex:outputpanel>
<!--END OF MULTISELECT PIECE-->

        </apex:pageblock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

The only part that is relevant to this functionality is the section between `<!...BEGINNING OF MULTISELECT PIECE>` and `<!--END OF MULTISELECT PIECE-->`.

What I would like to know is if it is possible to use that section as an embedded Visual Force page within a Page Layout instead of overriding the entire Edit of the object with the whole VisualForce page. Is it possible ? How do I name the `extension="BreachVFControllerEdit"` at ?

I didn't include the Apex or the VisualForce component ("MultiselectPicklist") used by the page because I didn't want to make this any more confusing than I need but I can do that if needed.

Comment: You'd need to pull it out into its own page. And you'll have to live with two save buttons.

Comment: I guess what you're saying is that in order to save the selections made in that section I would need to press the a Save button within that embedded VF section within the Page Layout ?

Comment: Exactly that, yes.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to include multi-select portion of the visualforce page, you need to use `Standardcontroller` of that object whose detail page you will be working.

`extensions` can be same or you can create new class for `extensions`. Create reusable piece of code if that can be used for both the extensions (just in case).

You have to juggle between two `Save` buttons, one at Standard page `save` and other is Visualforce `save` button.